# Scalabel to BDD100k format

Tags: json, annotations, multilabel-classification

does anyone have a good heart knows how to use scalable with custom images to create a separate json per images? The scalabel generates only 1 json for all instead of one json per image

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample of one image annotations of BDD100k:

```
{
    "name": "0a3f8f94-0f3aab2e",
    "frames": [
        {
            "timestamp": 10000,
            "objects": [
                {
                    "category": "truck",
                    "id": 0,
                    "attributes": {
                        "occluded": false,
                        "truncated": false,
                        "trafficLightColor": "none"
                    },
                    "box2d": {
                        "x1": 378.000134,
                        "y1": 116.941709,
                        "x2": 776.400296,
                        "y2": 594.5419
                    }
                },
                {
                    "category": "car",
                    "id": 1,
                    "attributes": {
                        "occluded": true,
                        "truncated": false,
                        "trafficLightColor": "none"
                    },
                    "box2d": {
                        "x1": 199.20006,
                        "y1": 370.141811,
                        "x2": 391.200135,
                        "y2": 535.741877
                    }
                },
                {
                    "category": "car",
                    "id": 2,
                    "attributes": {
                        "occluded": true,
                        "truncated": false,
                        "trafficLightColor": "none"
                    },
                    "box2d": {
                        "x1": 367.200128,
                        "y1": 385.741816,
                        "x2": 390.000138,
                        "y2": 402.541823
                    }
                },
                {
                    "category": "car",
                    "id": 3,
                    "attributes": {
                        "occluded": true,
                        "truncated": false,
                        "trafficLightColor": "none"
                    },
                    "box2d": {
                        "x1": 134.400035,
                        "y1": 368.94181,
                        "x2": 204.000061,
                        "y2": 480.541854
                    }
                },
                {
                    "category": "area/drivable",
                    "id": 4,
                    "attributes": {},
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            363.381771,
                            602.437086,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            785.256481,
                            602.437086,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            862.881428,
                            691.874524,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            697.506542,
                            664.874543,
                            "C"
                        ],
                        [
                            505.131674,
                            634.499564,
                            "C"
                        ],
                        [
                            273.944333,
                            701.999517,
                            "C"
                        ],
                        [
                            363.381771,
                            602.437086,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "area/alternative",
                    "id": 5,
                    "attributes": {},
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            181.131897,
                            539.999629,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            400.506746,
                            546.749624,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            262.131841,
                            701.999517,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            216.569372,
                            686.812028,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            181.131897,
                            539.999629,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "lane/single white",
                    "id": 6,
                    "attributes": {
                        "direction": "parallel",
                        "style": "dashed"
                    },
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            428.447371,
                            525.647371,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            246.836844,
                            699.584214,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "lane/single white",
                    "id": 7,
                    "attributes": {
                        "direction": "parallel",
                        "style": "dashed"
                    },
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            431.005265,
                            537.157898,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            277.53158,
                            704.700004,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "lane/single white",
                    "id": 8,
                    "attributes": {
                        "direction": "parallel",
                        "style": "dashed"
                    },
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            205.910527,
                            511.57895,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            175.21579,
                            524.368424,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": "lane/single white",
                    "id": 9,
                    "attributes": {
                        "direction": "parallel",
                        "style": "dashed"
                    },
                    "poly2d": [
                        [
                            208.468422,
                            520.531582,
                            "L"
                        ],
                        [
                            180.33158,
                            530.763161,
                            "L"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "attributes": {
        "weather": "snowy",
        "scene": "city street",
        "timeofday": "night"
    }
```